# Potential energy of parallel plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, voltage, capacitance

**Question**

What should the potential difference between two oppositely charged parallel plates be, in order for an electron that is shot from the positively charged plate with a speed of $2.5 \cdot 10^4$ m/s to just barley reach the negative plate?

**Attempted solution**

I just used energy, that is, I know that $\Delta v = Ed$ for parallel plates, and I want this $\Delta V$ to be equal to the change in kinetic energy, which is $\Delta K_E = \frac{mv^2}{2} - 0$. Thus $\Delta V = \frac{mv^2}{2} \approx 2.84\cdot 10^{-22}$ V. The answer provided is 1.8 mV. I don't see where I went wrong here.

Comment: Kinetic energy is not measured in volts. You are confusing potential and potential energy.

Comment: Ah, that did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric potential in not the potential energy, but the potential energy divided by the particle charge. So you need to add the charge of the electron to your equation: $ e{\cdot}ΔV=mv^2/2$